# What are the column definitions for H2O's gains/lift table?

Tags: model, h2o

H2O's [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#interpreting-the-gains-lift-chart) doesn't provide clear definitions for each column in the gains/lift table output. I'm not sure how the capture rate is being calculated, and there is a *score* column that is not mentioned in the documentation.

[Here's what the output looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FSFf.png)

The raw java file is [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/GainsLift.java) -- I tried finding the answer to my question in there but had difficulty making sense of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given row x in the table:

cumulative_data_fraction = number in group x / all observations

lower_threshold = minimum of predicted probability in group x

lift = response_rate / overall response rate (i.e., cumulative_response_rate in group 16)

cumulative_lift = cumulative_response_rate / overall response rate

response_rate = percent of responses in group x

score = average of predicted probability in group x

cumulative_response_rate = response rate for all observations in groups 1 through x

cumulative_score = average of predicted probability for all observations in groups 1 through x

capture_rate = percent of all responses that are in group x

cumulative_capture_rate = percent of all responses that are in groups 1 through x

gain = (lift - 1) * 100

cumulative_gain = (cumulative_lift - 1) * 100

Answer (score 2):

The capture rate is the proportion of all the events that fall into the group/bin. E.g. if 90 out of total 100 positive outcomes/events fall into the first bin, then the capture rate for that bin is 0.9.